# Why does setTimeout not work on an AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wait

I have this very simple jQuery function:

```
$(".milestone-in-tree").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        setTimeout(
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"/projects/pmnodes/" + $(this).data("pmnode") + "/addbuttons.js"
        }),5000)
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(".grid-btn").delay(800).remove();
    }
});
```

I want to make it wait 5 secs before sending the AJAX request to the server but it doesn't wait, it just sends it right away. Why?

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for all the feedbacks. I changed the function as it is suggested in all the answers:

```
$(".milestone-in-tree").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var node = $(this).data("pmnode")
        setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"/projects/pmnodes/" + node + "/addbuttons.js"
        }),5000});
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(".grid-btn").delay(800).remove();
    }
});
```

But I still get no delay. Is there something I misunderstood?
PS: I created the node variable because, for a reason I ignore, $(this) is not accessible anymore inside the SetTimeout anonymous function.

**UPDATE 2**

Finally, I could manage to get the delay but I realized that the request was still sent to the server after the delay, even if the mouseleave event had been triggered in between...

I could find a workaround. It is totally different. The delay doesn't work anymore but the ajax requests are aborted on mouseleave events, which is what I really needed. For the ones who might be interested, this is the code:

```
var button_request;
$(".milestone-in-tree").live({
    mouseover: function() {
        var node = $(this).data("pmnode");
        button_request = $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url:"/projects/pmnodes/" + node + "/addbuttons.js"
                    });
        setTimeout(function() {button_request;},5000)
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        if (button_request) {
            button_request.abort();
            button_request = null;
                }
        $(".grid-btn").remove();
    }
});
```

Of course the setTimeout could be removed (as it doesn't work...) but I leave it for clarity.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WzeJb/1/ -- caching the variable works just fine (check your browser's debugger). However, you need to put the `,5000` after that closing brace, not before it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".milestone-in-tree").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var pmnode = $(this).data("pmnode"); // cache the data in a variable
        setTimeout( function() { // this function(){...} wrapper is necessary
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"/projects/pmnodes/" + pmnode + "/addbuttons.js"
            })
        },5000)
    },
...
```

The first argument of a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) call needs to be either a string (which you really, really shouldn't do) or a self-contained function object.

By putting `$.ajax(...)` there instead, you're telling JavaScript to (1) run it immediately and (2) set the first argument as *whatever the ajax function returns* -- which, according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), is a jqXHR object which `setTimeout` can't do anything with.

Just get in the habit of putting an anonymous `function(){...}` as the first argument of `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` every time you use it, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Not entirely sure why this has been downvoted, looks correct to me! +1 to (attempt to) counter.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Maybe because of the complete lack of an explanation?

Comment: +1 this is correct answer, down voted like most others here including me

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for so many answers! I'm really impressed. However, it still doesn't work. When I add the anonymous function, $(this).data("pmnode") is reported as undefined. What's wrong? Thx again.

Comment: Updated the answer -- didn't occur to me that you'd have to cache that variable.

Answer (score 6):

`setTimeout()` either accepts a string of Javascript code which it `eval`s (very bad practice, might I add), **or** a function reference that it calls after a specified time.

What you're doing here is neither --- you're calling a function as a first parameter to `setTimeout()`. Because of that, it doesn't wait.

You want:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({});
}, 5000);
```

It's like the difference between:

```
setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

and

```
setTimeout(foo(), 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're calling the `$.ajax()` function, and passing whatever is returned by that call, to `setTimeout()`. You need to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"/projects/pmnodes/" + $(this).data("pmnode") + "/addbuttons.js"
    })
},5000);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for so many answers! I'm really impressed. However, it still doesn't work. When I add the anonymous function, $(this).data("pmnode") is reported as undefined. What's wrong? Thx again. –

Answer (score 2):

Wrap in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"/projects/pmnodes/" + $(this).data("pmnode") + "/addbuttons.js"
        });
},5000)
```

Comment: It seems most of us have been down voted including me without explanation +1 from my end.

Comment: @Sarfraz +1 back at you to counter the -1

Answer (score 2):

You are calling it straight away, put it in function callback:

```
   setTimeout( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"/projects/pmnodes/" + $(this).data("pmnode") + "/addbuttons.js"
    })
   } ,5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you are passing in is actually being executed, if you want to run code inside the first argument you need to wrap it in a function:

```
$(".milestone-in-tree").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        setTimeout(
function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"/projects/pmnodes/" + $(this).data("pmnode") + "/addbuttons.js"
        }),5000);
}
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(".grid-btn").delay(800).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it needs a `function()`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
        ...
}, 5000)
```